# Are post conditions of a routine a subset of precondtions?

Tags: design

Like the title says. The post conditions of a routine must be a subset of the preconditions for the routine?

The way I understand post-conditions is that they are entirely independent of preconditions, so my understanding leads me to think that they are not a subset of preconditions.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about a concrete example:

```
int x;
// Preconditions: none (empty set)
// Postconditions: x = y
void assign_to_x(int y) { x = y; }
```

If you allow any form of mutable state in your program, you can have postconditions that are not subsets of your preconditions.

Comment: Thank you! That makes it clearer. EDIT: I'm new here, is there an upvote button somewhere?

Comment: @user106857 Click the checkmark beside the answer, it both gives bstamour rep and marks the question as answered

Comment: +1 Excellent answer. Suggest you expand it to explain more fully.